# CSS form doesn't appear to have any line breaks

Tags: html, css

I'm working on styling my website forms and found a tutorial that seems to work up to a point...  The tutorial includes code to have hover hints, and this code is causing things to get ugly.  Instead of the fields all lining up under one another they seem to be attempting to position themselves one right after another and wrapping all the way down the window.

Here is the code element for the feature in question followed by the CSS...

HTML

```
<form id="defaultform" class="rounded" name="form2" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="hostess_fname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="input" name="hostess_fname" value="" id="hostess_fname" />
                <p class="hint">Enter your name.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="input" name="hostess_fname" value="" id="hostess_lname" />
                <p class="hint">Enter your email.</p>
            </div>
             <input type="submit" value="Lookup Hostess" />
<input type="hidden" name="Lookup" value="form2" />
```

CSS

```
#defaultform {

width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
background: #f0f0f0;
overflow:auto;

/* Border style */
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;

/* Border Shadow */
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;

}

label {
font-family: Arial, Verdana;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right:10px;
text-align: right;
width: 120px;
line-height: 25px;
font-size: 15px;
}

#defaultform.input{
font-family: Arial, Verdana;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #b9bdc1;
width: 300px;
color: #797979;
}

.hint{
display: none;
}

.field:hover .hint {
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin: -30px 0 0 455px;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 7px 10px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
}
```

I just updated the code with more of the HTML from a shorter form that I was trying with the same CSS.  I also added some more of the CSS code.  I'm getting the same behavior.  I'm still confused on selectors and how those are defined and stuff.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your problem? Because it [appears to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLNW/) unless I misunderstood what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 3):

I see what you're doing now that you've added your code. It's a pretty simple fix, but hard to catch:

CSS

```
.field{
    clear:both;
}
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcJ28/)**